# Turn-Based iPhone Game / OpenFeint

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, openfeint

I trying to create a turn-based game. And I want to use OpenFeint.

I found some info in the OpenFeint [documentation](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/openfeint-api-for-iOS-turn-based-multiplayer-implementation-guide/), but I can't find any API?

Also, can I just create a turn-based game using OpenFeints challenges/push notifications?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: That very page you hyperlinked in your question mentions about two samples where you can load up and peek into the source code. Did you try those samples first?

Answer (score 1):

I actually just talked to someone at OF about this yesterday. If you want the turn based SDK you need to email the OF help desk and ask for it. The download is no longer available from their site. The package they give you has a couple sample programs. If you can find it online you are looking for version 1.1.4. Anything before that may not be compatible with the main OF SDK available on their site today. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: PS I could probably send it to you.